connect to db2 for zos using python client ibm_db
I am new to ibm cloud environment.
I have deployed an image ibm-zos-3-1-s390x-dev-test-wazi-2 to ibm virtual instance.
I have changed the password and created a new user which I can connect via external python client.
I am able to telnet the host and IP address. firewall is not an issue.
But when I tried to connect to it using following python code.
import ibm_db

# Connection details
conn_str = (
    "Driver={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};"
    "DATABASE=DBD1LOC;"
    "HOSTNAME=***********;"
    "PORT=8102;"
    "PROTOCOL=TCPIP;"
    "UID=IBMUSER;"
    "PWD=**************;"
    "SECURITY=SSL;"
    "SSLServerCertificate=/workspace/common_cacert;"
)
try:
    conn = ibm_db.connect(conn_str, "", "")
    print("Connected to DB2 database on z/OS")
    print(conn)
    # Execute a query
    # sql = "SELECT * FROM SYSIBM.SYSDATABASE"
    sql = "SELECT * FROM SYSIBM.SYSTABLES"
    stmt = ibm_db.exec_immediate(conn, sql)
    
    # Fetch and print results
    result = ibm_db.fetch_assoc(stmt)
    while result:
        print(result)
        result = ibm_db.fetch_assoc(stmt)

    # Close the connection
    ibm_db.close(conn)
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Failed to connect to DB2 database on z/OS: {e}")


It errors out
Failed to connect to DB2 database on z/OS: [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2] SQL0805N  Package "DBD1LOC.NULLID.SYSSH200.5359534C564C3031" was not found.  SQLSTATE=51002 SQLCODE=-805

I have copied the trial license to the clidriver/license folder.
validate command output
./db2cli validate                      

===============================================================================
Client information for the current copy:
===============================================================================

Client Package Type       : IBM Data Server Driver For ODBC and CLI
Client Version (level/bit): DB2 v11.5.9.0 (special_36648/64-bit)
Client Platform           : Linux/X8664
Install/Instance Path     : ..
DB2DSDRIVER_CFG_PATH value: <not-set>
db2dsdriver.cfg Path      : ../cfg/db2dsdriver.cfg
DB2CLIINIPATH value       : <not-set>
db2cli.ini Path           : ../cfg/db2cli.ini
db2diag.log Path          : db2diag.log

===============================================================================
db2dsdriver.cfg schema validation for the entire file:
===============================================================================

Failure: Internal error while loading xml4c library. Validation cannot continue
         further. Contact IBM technical support to rectify the issue.

my db2dsdriver.cfg
<configuration>
    <databases>
        <database name="DBD1LOC">
            <hostname>******</hostname>
            <port>8102</port>
            <protocol>TCPIP</protocol>
            <security>
                <value>SSL</value>
                <certificateLabel>sslServerCertificate</certificateLabel>
            </security>
            <userid>IBMUSER</userid>
            <password>******</password>
        </database>
    </databases>
    <dsdriver>
        <common>
            <logpath>/workspace</logpath>
        </common>
    </dsdriver>
</configuration>

I am not sure how to resolve this error

The bindfiles in your clidriver subdirectory tree need to be bound to the target subsystem, so the connecting authid may need additional permission. Ask you ZDBA for help, current clidriver is 11.5.9 version, use the 'db2cli bind' command with suitable arguments.

We don't have a ZDBA. When I tried to bind using command ./db2cli bind $IBM_DB_HOME/bnd/db2cli.lst -database DBD1LOC:*****:8102 -user ibmuser -passwd ***** -options "grant public action replace blocking no" It errored out as ```Database connection failed.
[IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30081N  A communication error has been detected. Communication protocol being used: "TCP/IP".  Communication API being used: "SOCKETS".  Location where the error was detected: "150.239.165.183".  Communication function detecting the error: "recv".  Protocol specific error code(s): "104", "*", "0".  SQLSTATE=08001

The bind action cannot connect, because the db2dsdriver.cfg looks incorrect, database and dsn stanzas need parameter for actual cert file via sslServerCertificate parameter. Fix the xml4c prob first, then fix db2dsdriver.cfg,  then get db2cli validate -connect...working with successful connections.Only then Finally try bind. This is all config, not programming, so out of scope for stacko erflow.
